# How to get the preapprovalKey using PayPal Adaptive Payments API only if user completes the preapproval process?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal Adaptive Payments. I have succesfully redirected the user to the PayPal preapproval process for some periodic/automatic payments our product needs. However, I have the following issue.

When the user is redirected to the logging screen on PayPal for the preapproval process, even if the user has not signed in yet, PayPal already gives me a preapproval JSON with the key:

```
    { responseEnvelope: 
    { timestamp: '2013-11-28T18:38:58.726-08:00',
    ack: 'Success',
    correlationId: 'XXXXXXX',
    build: 'XXXXXXX' },
    preapprovalKey: 'PA-XXXXXXX',
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    preapprovalUrl: 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=PA-XXXXXXX' }
```

However, the big issue here is that I should not save the preapprovalKey yet on my DB, because the user could abort the preapproval process since he/she has not signed in yet. I should save it, only if the user complete the process.

**I would like to know if there is a method to get the preapproval response *only if the users finishes the preapproval process*.**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal sends 2 kinds of notifications when a preapproval is approved by the user, as their docs explains:

> **Notifications are sent after preapproval is complete:**
>
> 1. PayPal sends an email to the sender that confirmed the approval.
> 2. PayPal sends an IPN message to the URL specified in the
>      ipnNotificationUrl field of the Preapproval request.

So, you need to receive the post response sent to the custom ipnNotificationUrl you specify in your preapproval request. In this JSON comes a field named: "approved" where you can check a 'true' or 'false' string to verify if the user approved the transaction.

More info in PayPal's docs: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/